# Google YouTube API 3 OAuth does not ask user for permission on second login

Tags: javascript, api, oauth, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube API 3 for my app. When a user logs in for the first time he/she is asked to give consent for the app to access their YouTube account.

```
window.location = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth? 
client_id='+client_id+'&
redirect_uri='+redirect_uri+'&
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube&
response_type=token';
```

If the user logs out using a request to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token='+token`, the default behavior is that when they are redirected to the first link above, they are automatically logged in without being required to click for consent. I want the user to re-approve the application for YouTube access each time after logging out.

As described in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent), I added the parameters `prompt=consent&include_granted_scopes=false` to the url request, but this only prompts the user to re-allow Google offline access. It does not re-prompt the user for YouTube access.

How can I get the auth link url to request permissions for the YouTube API scope on a repeat login?

Answer (score 0):

Please try [revoking a token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) wherein part of the removal process can include an API request to ensure the permissions granted to the application are removed.

To programmatically revoke a token, using HTTP/REST, your application makes a request to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke` and includes the token as a parameter:

```
curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
```

**Important Note:** Following a successful revocation response, it might take some time before the revocation has full effect.